# Eloquent ORM all() not returning anything

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Shoot me down if I this is a silly question, but I am really struggling to get this `all()` function working for me. It is returning empty list for me. Any help will be highly appreciated. I have got 2 rows in the newsletters table

Model looks like this -

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Newsletters extends Eloquent {

//use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
use SoftDeletingTrait; // <-- Use This Insteaf Of protected $softDelete = true;


/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'newsletters';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array    */


protected $guarded = array('newsletterId');
protected $fillable = array('name', 'subject','from_email','from_name');

public static $rules = array(
    'name' => 'required|min:5',
    'subject' => 'required|min:5',
    'from_email' => 'required|email',
    'from_name' => 'required'
);

}
```

My call in the controller is like this -

```
<?php

class newslettersController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //$newsletters = Newsletters::paginate(3);      
    $newsletters = Newsletters::all();
    echo $newsletters;exit();
    return View::make('newsletters.index', compact('newsletters'));
}
```

Comment: To start with the obvious, are there any rows in the `newsletters` table? Does `dd($newsletters);` output anything?

Comment: @ceejayoz *"I have got 2 rows in the newsletters table"*

Comment: There are 2 rows in the table. and dd($newsletters) gives the follwoing 
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#215 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Are you sure `newsletters` is the correct table name?

Comment: Yes they are in newsletters table. The funny thing is that store is working fine for the same table - Newsletters::create($input);

Comment: Is the `deleted_at` field `NULL`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter they are timestamp data type and tehy have a default of 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: That's your problem. Default should be `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any value - even `0000-00-00 00:00:00` - in the `deleted_at` column tells Laravel that the item has been deleted. Change your default value for that column to `NULL` or new items will be flagged as deleted on creation.

The `$table->softDeletes()` Schema function does this automatically if you use it in a migration.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you use the `SoftDeletingTrait` a global scope will be applied to every query with your model so all records where `deleted_at` is **not `NULL`** will be ignored.

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope`:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder)
{
    $model = $builder->getModel();

    $builder->whereNull($model->getQualifiedDeletedAtColumn()); // <<-- this

    $this->extend($builder);
}
```

Change the default of your `deleted_at` column to `NULL` and update the existing records to be `NULL` as well.

Comment: Thanks! I had to accept ceejayoz's answer as he answered first. But both were correct.

Comment: Well actually I find it out first in the comments :P

Comment: @lukasgeiter Have a +1 from me for that. :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure newsletters is the correct table name as @Ray said.
Try this:

```
$newsLetters = DB::table('newsletters')->get();
```

Comment: Bypassing Eloquent loses a lot of its useful functionality.